# is it feasible to open multiple conn in NpgSQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, entity-framework, model-view-controller

My current web application that's developed in ASP.NET using Entity Framework MVC has a bug. What I did is that when ever a user registers, I create his database from a template database and therefor all the registered users have the same database schema.

When ever User#1 opens a session and connects to his assigned database `"Server=localhost; User Id=postgres; Password=Password$; port=5432; Database=USER1_DB; Pooling=false;"` as soon as User2 login the User1 looses his initial connection string because it's been replaced with `"Server=localhost; User Id=postgres; Password=Password$; port=5432; Database=USER2_DB; Pooling=false;"`.

I understand the problem in my code because when ever a login action is performed `public IActionResult Login(Homepage acc){...}` I am establishing a `NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection();` and change the connection string: `conn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; User Id=postgres; Password=Password$; port=5432; Database=" + USERID + "_DB; Pooling=false;";`

All the other users loose there initial connections string...

Is there a way to have multiple `conn.open` so that each conn is assigned to the concerned user while running the web app?

Thank you

Comment: You need a  different instance of the Connection object for each user.  It looks like you have only one connection object.

Comment: how can it be done?

Comment: Without seeing the code how can we advise? It certainly looks like you are reusing the connection object

Comment: public void dBChange(string UserName)
        {
            string curConn = Startup.companyString;
            List<string> curConnList = curConn.Split(";", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            curConnList[4] = " Database=" + UserName;
            string newConn = string.Empty;
            foreach (string Connection in curConnList)
            {
                newConn += Connection + ";";
            }
            Startup.companyString = newConn;
        }